# moc: Unknown option -isystem

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, moc, scorep

I am trying to install [score-p](http://www.vi-hps.org/projects/score-p/). It has standard build chain. I passed the configuration part successfully. Makefile was generated automatically after configuration. Then I did `make` and got an error. The problem is  `moc` complains that `-isystem` is an unknown option. The option is embedded in `QT_CPPFLAGS`. If I delete this option then `moc` complains that too many input files were specified. What should I do?

```
$(editor_plugin_moc_o): ../src/GUI-qt/plugins/SourceCodeEditor/%.moc.cpp: $(SRC_ROOT)src/GUI-qt/plugins/SourceCodeEditor/%.h
    @echo "Create moc file $@"
    @$(MKDIR_P) ../src/GUI-qt/plugins/SourceCodeEditor
    @$(MOC) $(QT_CPPFLAGS) $(CUBE_INCLUDES) $(GUI_INCLUDES) $(CUBE_DEBUG_FLAGS) $(DEFINE_TRACE_BROWSER) $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GCC `-isystem` option takes an argument, so it would be something like `-isystem /some/dir/include`.  You can't just remove the `-isystem` option without removing its argument as well.

However, it seems likely that if you remove both of them you'll get compile errors because header files cannot be found.

I recommend you try turning the `-isystem` option into a normal `-I` option, that moc will understand:

```
@$(MOC) $(patsubst -isystem,-I,$(QT_CPPFLAGS)) $(CUBE_INCLUDES) $(GUI_INCLUDES) $(CUBE_DEBUG_FLAGS) $(DEFINE_TRACE_BROWSER) $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency structure is a bit off:

You want something like:

```
%.o : %.moc.cpp %.cpp
    @echo "Normal compilation of object file goes here"

%.moc.cpp: %.cpp
    moc $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) -i $< -o $@
```

Note that the `moc.cpp` file and the source `cpp` file chain to the same object file (because the `moc.cpp` is really additional source code for your main `cpp` file which you let `moc` generate for you). Also note that you need to have a rule to actually generate that `moc.cpp` file, where you pass `moc` correct defines and includes. Finally: you do not pass `moc` things like `-isystem` or other compiler specific flags, just the defines & the includes.

See the documentation which has a complete section on `moc` with Makefiles at: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html